# Is There a way to update/refresh only one record in delphi dbgrid?

Tags: delphi, refresh, record, dbgrid

Is it possible? How?

Comment: The correct word would be 'record'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what dataset you linked with the DBGrid. TClientDataset can.

Comment: See if the IBDAC documentation says anything about it. Since I never used, I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

If the TDBGrid was connected to a memory dataset you could. You would query the database for the selected record by ID, while modifying it (selected record) with the results (in-memory) you obtained.

Answer (score 0):

What is your DataSet for the DataSource in DBGrid ?

If you are using ADOConnection, and working with ADOTable or ADOQuery as the DataSet, then you can try the following script :

```
ADOTable1.close;
ADOTable1.open;
```

or

```
ADOQuery1.close;
ADOQuery1.open;
```

Those scripts above will refresh the whole DBGrid.

As long as I know, there is now way to refresh one record in DBGrid. Correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the ID before refresh, and then you locate the same ID by positioning the cursor in the old Record. Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.refreshQuery;
var
   oldID: integer;
begin
   oldID :=query1Id_table.AsInteger;
   query1.Refresh;
   //or if refresh not works
   //query1.close;
   //query1.open;
   query1.Locate('Id_table',oldID,[]);
end;
```

or depends of DataSet, see if this function works:

```
query1.RefreshCurrentRow;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a input box asking something specific getting a value to look for the one you want to edit then you can use the locate function to find it and if it is found you edit and post

```
Var
    sRegisterNo, sAnswer : string;
Begin
    sAnswer := Inputbox('Registerno', 'Enter the user registerNo you want to edit' , '' );

    With dmName do
    Begin
        sRegisterNo := tblMembers['RegisterNo'];

        If sRegisterNo.locate(sAnswer,  'sRegisterNo') =  True then
        Begin
            tblMembers.edit;
            // Use edits to give the new values 
            // Ex. EdtRegisterno.text := RE001;
            tblMembers.post
        End;
    End;
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in C++Builder, so once converted to Delphi it should work.
You'll see there is a test for the number of records, this is because below about 500 records (from testing with my database) a full refresh was actually quicker than  filtering down to just the current record, refreshing it, unfiltering and then locating the original record.

```
int refreshDataSetRecord(TDataSet *DS, String PrimaryKeyFld, String srcVal)
 {
  int f = 0;
  try
   {
    if(DS->Active)
     {
      if(srcVal.Length() == 0)
       {srcVal = DS->FieldByName(PrimaryKeyFld)->AsString;}
      if((DS->Filtered) // means can't just re-filter    
       ||(DS->RecordCount < 500)) // test for quickest refresh method
       {
        DS->Refresh();
        f = 2;
       }
      else
       {
        DS->Filter = PrimaryKeyFld + " = '" + srcVal+"'";
        DS->Filtered = true;
        DS->Refresh();
        DS->Filtered = false;
        DS->Filter = "";
        f = 1;
       }    
      if(DS->FieldByName(PrimaryKeyFld)->AsString != srcVal)
       {
        TLocateOptions SearchOptns;
        SearchOptns.Clear();
        DS->Locate(PrimaryKeyFld, srcVal, SearchOptns);
       }
     }
   }
  catch(Exception &e)
   {
    f = -1;
    MessageDlg("Problem refreshing DataSet record(" + DS->Name+"," + 
      PrimaryKeyFld + ")\n" + e.Message, mtError, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, 0);
   }
  catch(...)
   {
    f = -1;
    MessageDlg("Undisclosed problem refreshing DataSet record(" + DS->Name + "," 
      + PrimaryKeyFld + ")", mtError, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, 0);
   }
  return f;
 }
```